# An object passed as const to a function returns a pointer to its data and the compiler complains

Tags: c++

I don't need to modify the data ... merely to pass it along to a function that expects a const version of the data.

OtherList[i]->Data returns a pointer. How can I calm down the compiler ?

```
template<class AnyVar>
void TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>::Insert (const TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>& OtherList, unsigned AtIndex)
{
    const unsigned Len=OtherList.ListSize();
    if (Len==0) return;

    for (unsigned i=0;i<Len;i++) {Insert(OtherList[i]->Data,AtIndex++);}
}
```

EDIT:
The error message

```
error: passing 'const TypeLinkedList<float>' as 'this' argument of 'TypeNode<AnyVar, 2u>* TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>::operator[](unsigned int) [with AnyVar = float]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
```

The function declarations are:

```
void    Insert  (const AnyVar& Value, unsigned AtIndex=0); 
void    Insert  (const TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>& OtherList, unsigned AtIndex);
TypeNode<AnyVar,2>*  operator[]   (const unsigned idx){if (idx<Size) return NodeAt(idx); else if (Size==0) return nullptr; else return NodeAt(Size-1);}
```

EDIT 2:

Someone suggested to overload the operator[] with a const, but that doesn't work either:

```
   const TypeNode<AnyVar,2>*  operator[]   (const unsigned idx) const {if (idx<Size) return NodeAt(idx); else if (Size==0) return nullptr; else return NodeAt(Size-1);}
```

ERROR:

```
error: passing 'const TypeLinkedList<float>' as 'this' argument of 'TypeNode<AnyVar, 2u>* TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>::NodeAt(unsigned int) [with AnyVar = float]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
```

Comment: Would it be too much to ask to show the error message? Also, you apparently have another overload of `Insert` you are calling from the one you've shown - how is it declared?

Comment: Please post the error message. May be subscript operator[] for TypeLinkedList doesn't have an overload on const.

Comment: Is `NodeAt` const?  I think that's what the last error is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `const` overload for `operator[]` in your `TypeLinkedList` template class. Provide one and you'll be settled:

```
template<class AnyVar>
void TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>::operator[](unsigned AtIndex) { ... }

template<class AnyVar>
void TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>::operator[](unsigned AtIndex) const { ... }
//                                                        ^^^^^
```

On a side note your function doesn't make much sense. For a container type the `insert` function should probably just take the element, instead of passing some other container and the index in said container.

Comment: There are two insert functions. One for an element and one for an entire list.

Comment: @ThomasAn What does the one "for an entire list" do that the other can't?

Comment: The operator[] cannot be a constant, in all other cases I need to return a node and actually modify its content.

Comment: @ThomasAn You can provide both const and non-const overloads.

Comment: @ ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ: One of them inserts a value into the existing list, the other transplants an entire different list into the current list.

Comment: @ThomasAn That would be a copy constructor. Not your `Insert(const TypeLinkedList<AnyVar>& OtherList, unsigned AtIndex)` member function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87662/discussion-between-yere-and-thomas-an).

Comment: You mean to add a second operator[] function that returns const reference of a pointer ? I'll have to google this. Not sure how to do this on top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

As i supposed: subscript operator[] for TypeLinkedList doesn't have an overload on const. Simple example for overload without bounds checking:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Test
{
public:
    T& operator[](std::size_t idx) { return m_data[idx]; }
    const T& operator[](std::size_t idx) const { return m_data[idx]; }

private:
    T *m_data = new T[10];
};

main(){
    Test<int> t1;
    const Test<int> t2;
    std::cout << t1[0]  // calls first non const method
              << t2[0]; // calls second  const method
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error.
The operator[] does not return a reference to the same class. It returns a pointer to a node. I added some edits on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The operator[] is using the NodeAt() function and the node at function needs to modify the list. There is a bookmark facility that updates on every query. Each time we index to somewhere the bookmark changes. Therefore I cannot use const at all, I have to roll back to plain.

Comment: Understand. But may be you should consider declare your bookmark facility as mutable, if NodeAt method is logically const.

Comment: @Elohim: That is a VERY good point and likely the only moral lesson in this thread. I made this change ASAP and it now compiles fine (along with the operator[] const change).

Comment: @ThomasAn - You can delete your own question.

Comment: @Bo: It will not let you delete a question if it already has answers